# codeigniter pagination in multiple table joins displying error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a problem with pagination.when I click on the next but it brings the above error, but when I click on the previous link it works normally. here is my code for the controller:

```
public function categoryfour()

{

$config = array();

    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "bulletins/categoryfour";

    $total_row = $this->news_model->record_count_category_four();

    $config["total_rows"] = $total_row;

    $config["per_page"] = 2;

    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;


    $config['num_links'] = $total_row;

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';

    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';

    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';

    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["posts"] =$this->news_model->get_news_cat_four($config["per_page"], $page);

    $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data["pages"] = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links );

    $this->load->view('category_one',$data);
}
```

here is the code for the model:

```
function get_news_cat_four($limit, $start)
{

    $this->db->select('news.id as newsId,news_category.id as catId,users.id as userId,news.*,news_category.*,users.*,comments.*, COUNT(comments.post_id) as num_comments');

    $this->db->join('users' , 'users.id = news.user_id');

    $this->db->join('news_category' , 'news_category.cat_id = news.news_id');

    $this->db->join('comments' , 'comments.post_id = news.id');

    $this->db->group_by('comments.post_id');

    $this->db->order_by('news.date_added','desc');

    $this->db->where('news.news_id',4);

    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);

    $query = $this->db->get("news");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;}
```

and finally the view:

```
<div id="page-content" class="single-page container">

    <div class="gutter-7px">

        <div id="main-content" class="col-md-8 fix-right">

            <article class="single-post">

            <?php if(count($posts)) { 

              foreach($posts as $n){ ?>

                <div class="entry-header">

                    <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php echo base_url('bulletins/view/'.$n->newsId)?>"><?php echo $n->title;?></a></h1>
                    <span> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <?php echo date( 'F jS, Y g:i a' , strtotime($n->date_added))?>/ 

               <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>

               <?php echo $n->num_comments;?>/<i class="fa fa-user"></i> 

                   <?php echo $n->username?></span>

                </div>
                <div class="post-thumbnail-wrap"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>bulletins/view/<?php echo $n->newsId?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/'.$n->image)?>"
                 style="width:800px;height:500px" /></a></div>

                <div class="entry-content">
                            <p><?php echo  substr(strip_tags($n->content), 0, 200).'...';?></p>
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>bulletins/view/<?php echo $n->newsId?>">Read More...</a>
                            <?php }}?>
                            </div>

            </article>
            <div id="pagination">
             <ul class="pagination">

             <!-- Show pagination links -->
             <?php foreach ($pages as $link) {

              echo "<li>". $link."</li>";

               } 
              ?>

            </div>

    </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Try this `if( $posts && count($posts) > 0 ) {`

Comment: @PraveenKumar the error disappeared on clicking on the links but displays  empty pages.

Comment: Then use an else case of this `if` condition and write `echo "Sorry but no posts on this page....;"`

Comment: Also i think that `$data["posts"] =$this->news_model->get_news_cat_four($config["per_page"], $page);` should be `$data["posts"] =$this->news_model->get_news_cat_four($config["per_page"], $page * $config["per_page"] );`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I can be be able to see "Sorry but no posts on this page....;" in the blank pages using if else

Comment: Haha This means you have no post to show now... On this page.. debug your query to return results if there are any... `echo $ghtis->db->last_query();` will help you on the way :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar there is still no change even after adding $data["posts"] =$this->news_model->get_news_cat_four($config["per_page"], $page * $config["per_page"] );

Comment: Then undo this change and start digging ;)

Comment: I can't really figure out why this query  is behaving like this. since it only works well in the first link and moving forward it doesn't work.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have a lot of posts related to that particular category ID

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy.this has finally worked for me. I debugged using echo $this->db->last_query(); and I realized there was one joined table which was not working properly.